# How to give hints to fix kerning of "Two" in sffamily

Tags: pdftex, kerning

Is there any way to improve sffamily kerning globally? (for example in my document preamble; I really don't want to edit font files or system settings)

The `Tw` combination looks awful; `Two` is even worse. I would like to set this up somewhere in my document header rather than having to fix every instance.

I'm not a professional typographer so I don't know what I should use.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagecolor{white}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\node[align=left] at (0,0) {One is the loneliest number \\ Two can be as bad as one \\ Three Dog Night};
\node[align=left] at (0,-2) {with manual kerning:\\One is the loneliest number \\ T{\kern -0.1em}w{}o can be as bad as one \\ Three Dog Night};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using pdftex (via TikzEdt) if that matters.

Answer (score 8):

With lualatex you could adjust the kerning (I'm overdoing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
name = "ktest",
type="kern",
data = {
  ["T"] = {
       ["w"] = -200,
          }
      }}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily Two

\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}[RawFeature={+ktest;}]

\sffamily Two
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is the choice of the font designer, perhaps you prefer latin modern

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\textsf{Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textsf{Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been using various fonts for 20 years and I don't think I've *ever* second-guessed the font designer's kerning until now. Should I file a bug? I appreciate the suggestion but I like sffamily's look.

Comment: you could file a bug but the chance Prof. Knuth changes the cm font now is approxmately 0. changing the layout of some vast percentage of documents made over the last 40 years. In many ways that is the point of latin modern, it's the  cm design with updates... @JasonS

Comment: @JasonS are you sure you can visually distinguish lm sans serif from cm sans serif? (apart from improved kerning) latin modern is a copy of the computer modern design it doesn't have a different "look"

Comment: oh, I see, so they're supposed to be the same font with modern tweaks. I was confused because your rendering is different from mine (using pdftex), I thought it was a different font altogether.

Comment: I used pdftex @JasonS

Comment: That fixes the Tw, but the "wo" is still awfully close in pdftex (doesn't look bad in your rendering)

Comment: "I used pdftex" -- really? Huh, something must be different in my system setup.

Comment: @JasonS both lm and cm have  \kern-0.27779pt between w and o whch is a bit tight but ...

Comment: it's weird, though, your rendering looks fine for the built-in "wo", mine does not.

Comment: @JasonS but to answer your question, you can not change (or even detect) font kerns from within tex, so you would have to use a different font eg make a virtual font the same as cmss but with different kerns